# Problem with task list in htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

I have a .tex file as shown

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

    \item Question 1
    \begin{tasks}(1)
        \task[\textbf{a.}]Option 1
        \task[\textbf{b.}]Option 2
        \task[\textbf{c.}]Option 3
        \task[\textbf{d.}]Option 4
        
    \end{tasks}

    \item Question 2
    \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task[\textbf{a.}]Option A
    \task[\textbf{b.}]Option B
    \task[\textbf{c.}]Option C
    \task[\textbf{d.}]Option D
    
\end{tasks}
    
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

I'm attempting to convert a La-TeX document of mine to HTML using make4ht.The PDF output look  like this,[image] but the corresponding HTML code has is producing something different.
[image]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">

    
    <body>
    <ol class="enumerate1">
    <li class="enumerate" id="x1-3x1">Question 1 <a id="x1-4r1"></a> <!--l. 17-->
    <p class="noindent"><!--l. 17--></p>
    <p class="noindent">Option 1</p>
    <!--l. 17-->
    <p class="noindent"><span class="rm-lmbx-12">a.</span> <a id="x1-5r2"></a></p>
    <!--l. 17-->
    <p class="noindent"></p>
    <!--l. 17-->
    <p class="noindent">Option 2</p>
    <!--l. 17-->
    <p class="noindent"><span class="rm-lmbx-12">b.</span> <a id="x1-6r3"></a></p>
    <!--l. 17-->
    <p class="noindent"></p>
    <!--l. 17-->
    <p class="noindent">Option 3</p>
    <!--l. 17-->
    <p class="noindent"><span class="rm-lmbx-12">c.</span> <a id="x1-7r4"></a></p>
    <!--l. 17-->
    <p class="noindent"></p>
    <!--l. 17-->
    <p class="noindent">Option 4</p>
    <!--l. 17-->
    <p class="noindent"><span class="rm-lmbx-12">d.</span></p>
    </li>
    <li class="enumerate" id="x1-9x2">Question 2 <a id="x1-10r1"></a> <!--l. 26-->
    <p class="noindent"><!--l. 26--></p>
    <p class="noindent">Option A</p>
    <!--l. 26-->
    <p class="noindent"><span class="rm-lmbx-12">a.</span><a id="x1-11r2"></a></p>
    <!--l. 26-->
    <p class="noindent">Option B</p>
    <!--l. 26-->
    <p class="noindent"><span class="rm-lmbx-12">b.</span> <a id="x1-12r3"></a></p>
    <!--l. 26-->
    <p class="noindent"></p>
    <!--l. 26-->
    <p class="noindent">Option C</p>
    <!--l. 26-->
    <p class="noindent"><span class="rm-lmbx-12">c.</span><a id="x1-13r4"></a></p>
    <!--l. 26-->
    <p class="noindent">Option D</p>
    <!--l. 26-->
    <p class="noindent"><span class="rm-lmbx-12">d.</span></p>
    </li>
    </ol>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I don't mind if make4ht cannot reproduce the multi column behavior of task package but is there any way to align the option label and option.What config file can do the job ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the `tasks` package uses Xcoffins to typeset particular items. Because all formatting is stripped, you get the items in the order in which they were sent. This is why task text goes before the label.

As `tasks` environment starts list, we can output particular tasks as `\item`. We can then use standard TeX4ht commands to configure output HTML for this list.

Here is the configuration file for the Tasks package, `tasks.4ht`. Place it to the same directory as is your document.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
% generate normal \item for tasks instead of coffins
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__tasks_task_fourht:nnn #1#2#3
  {\item[#1]{\__tasks_setup: #2 {#3}}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__tasks_task_fourht:nnn {VVV}

\HLet\__tasks_task:nnn\__tasks_task_fourht:nnn
\HLet\__tasks_task:VVV\__tasks_task_fourht:VVV

\ExplSyntaxOff
\Hinput{tasks}
\endinput
```

It redefines the command that typeset tasks to output `\item`. Now, you can configure the list in the `config.cfg` configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\ConfigureList{tasks}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="tasks">}\def\end@task{}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\end@task\HCode{</div>}}
{\end@task\HCode{<div class="task"><span class="label">}\def\end@task{\HCode{</div>}}}
{\HCode{</span>}\noindent}
\makeatother
\EndPreamble
```

The `\ConfigureList` command is used to configure list environments:

```
\ConfigureList.....................5

   #1   type of list (e.g., itemize, description, enumerate,
                            list, trivlist)
   #2   before list
   #3   after  list
   #4   before label
   #5   after label

   \DeleteMark   removes latex's label; to be placed at the end of #4
   \AnchorLabel  defines an anchor for \label in current item; to
                 be placed in #5
```

The `\end@task` command is used to close the current task, this is why it is defined as empty at the beginning of the environment and initialized only after the first task is opened.

Compile using:

```
 make4ht -c config.cfg filename.tex
```

I've expanded the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

    \item Question 1
    \begin{tasks}(1)
        \task[\textbf{a.}]Option 1
        \task[\textbf{b.}]Option 2
        \task[\textbf{c.}]Option 3
        \item[\textbf{d.}]Option 4
        \task Without explicit label
        \task! Full width
        \task*(7) Starred task
    \end{tasks}

    \item Question 2
    \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task[\textbf{a.}]Option A
    \task[\textbf{b.}]Option B
    \task[\textbf{c.}]Option C
    \task[\textbf{d.}]Option D
    
\end{tasks}
    
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

And HTML code:

```html
  <ol class='enumerate1'>
<li class='enumerate' id='x1-3x1'>
      <!-- l. 10 --><p class='noindent'>Question 1
      </p><div class='tasks'><div class='task'><span class='label'>
      </span>
      </div><div class='task'><span class='label'>
   <span class='cmbx-12'>a.</span> </span>Option 1
      </div><div class='task'><span class='label'>
  <span class='cmbx-12'>b.</span> </span>Option 2
      </div><div class='task'><span class='label'>
   <span class='cmbx-12'>c.</span> </span>Option 3
      </div><div class='task'><span class='label'>
  <span class='cmbx-12'>d.</span> </span>Option 4<a id='x1-4r1'></a>
      </div><div class='task'><span class='label'>
  a) </span>Without explicit label<a id='x1-5r2'></a>
      </div><div class='task'><span class='label'>
  b) </span>Full width<a id='x1-6r3'></a>
      </div><div class='task'><span class='label'>
   c) </span>Starred task</div></div>
      </li>
<li class='enumerate' id='x1-8x2'>
      <!-- l. 21 --><p class='noindent'>Question 2
      </p><div class='tasks'><div class='task'><span class='label'>
      </span>
      </div><div class='task'><span class='label'>
   <span class='cmbx-12'>a.</span> </span>Option A
      </div><div class='task'><span class='label'>
  <span class='cmbx-12'>b.</span> </span>Option B
      </div><div class='task'><span class='label'>
   <span class='cmbx-12'>c.</span> </span>Option C
      </div><div class='task'><span class='label'>
  <span class='cmbx-12'>d.</span> </span>Option D
      </div></div>
      </li></ol>
```

Edit:

To get the multicolumn support try this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{taskid}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ConfigureList{tasks}
{\stepcounter{taskid}\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div~class="tasks"~id="tasks-\arabic{taskid}">}\def\end@task{}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\end@task\HCode{</div>}
\Css{\#tasks-\arabic{taskid}{%
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(\int_use:N \l__tasks_columns_int, 1fr);
}}
}
{\end@task\HCode{<div~class="task" ><span~class="label">}\def\end@task{\HCode{</div>}}}
{\HCode{</span>}\noindent}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\Css{.task:first-child{display: none;}}
\makeatother
\EndPreamble
```

It declares unique ID for each tasks environment, and using CSS grid, it declares number of columns.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up vote. Thanks a lot michal. It saved my day @michal.h21

Comment: @PhysicsFuturing I've updated TeX4ht sources, so you will not need this code soon, if you update your TeX distribution.

Comment: BTW, Is there any way to keep the multi column behavior in tasks @michal.h21

Comment: @hfactor sure, see the edited answer